# Differentiate $F(x)=f(x)+(a+h-x)f'(x)+\frac{(a+h-x)^2}{2!}f''(x)+... + \frac{(a+h-x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(x)+k(a+h-x)^m$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Differentiate $F(x)=f(x)+(a+h-x)f'(x)+\frac{(a+h-x)^2}{2!}f''(x)+... + \frac{(a+h-x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(x)+k(a+h-x)^m$

I was trying to solve it following way.

$$F'(x)=f'(x)-f'(x)+(a+h-x)f''(x)-(a+h-x)f''(x)+\color{blue}{\frac{(a+h-x)^2}{2!}f'''(x)}+\frac{\color{red}{(n-1)}(a+h-x)^{n-2}}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}x+\frac{(a+h-x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(x)+km(a+h-x)^{m-1}(-1)$$

$$= \frac{(a+h-x)^2}{2!}f'''(x)+\frac{(n-1)(a+h-x)^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(x)+\frac{(a+h-x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(x)-km(a+h-x)^{m-1}$$

I had marked(with Red color) something. According to my book, it shouldn't be there. But, according to my calculation it should be there.

They didn't write the blue line also but, I don't have any problem on it cause, they put that as extra function (used `...` for that function).

---

The function I said to differentiate.

[image]

The way they differentiate.

[image]

Comment: @user10354138 As I know if something cancels than they should disappear from both side (numerator and denominator). But, here it only disappeared from numerator. Even, the value ($(n-1)!$) didn't decrease.

Comment: Huh?  It is right there as the first term of the middle line $\frac{(a+h-x)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}f^{(n-1)}(x)$.

Comment: @user10354138 I understood the problem. But, how it disappeared last line of book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{n-1}{(n-1)!}$$
$$=\frac{n-1}{(n-1)(n-2)!}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two types of **dots**, one **...**, and another **......**, as you see. The longer one is just a connection to the number of equation. and about the shorter one, if you notice, no **dots** remains, since all terms, but the two last, cancel, just like what you see in two first terms, also for last one that you misunderstand it, as I guess:
$$(... +  \frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-2)}}{(n-2)!}f^{(n-2)}(x)
       +  \frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(x) + ...)' =$$
$$ ... +(-\frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-3)}}{(n-3)!}f^{(n-2)}(x)
       +  \frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-2)}}{(n-2)!}f^{(n-1)}(x))+$$
$$     +(-\frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-2)}}{(n-2)!}f^{(n-1)}(x)
       +  \frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(x)) + ... =$$
$$ ... -  \frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-3)}}{(n-3)!}f^{(n-2)}(x)
       +  \frac{(a+h-x)^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(x)+...$$

Also in last line the left term cancel with a term in left **...**, and just the right term and terms after that in right **...** remains.

Comment: In last line $$\frac{(a+h-x)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} f^{(n-1)}x$$ where it had gone? I can merge the denominator to $\frac{(a+h-x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(x)$ but, how to merge numerator?

Comment: The term you miss, appears in right side of second line and left side of third line, but in different sign, so they cancel.